# La llave vs. la clave

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones, diferencias-regionales, etimología

*Nevermind the fact that these two words are both irregularly feminine*

I was always taught in school that `llave` is key, like the kind you use to open doors / crank a vehicle, etcetera.  Though when I learned one day that `llave` can also refer to the faucet on your sink or bathtub, I was, to say the least, confused.  My first instinctive idea was to figure out the link between a door key and a water faucet, and it has continue to stump me.

`Clave` on the other hand seems to be the more abstract way to say `key`... the kind of key you would hear about in a project.

> The **key** to understanding English is to expect anything.
>
> The key to eating healthy is to eat mainly fresh vegetables.

I know that `clave` is also understood in the musical context.

> This guitar is in the key of C minor. (@steverrill)
>
> He likes to touch the keys on the piano.

I realize there could be regional differences with these words, but I am interested to see whether there is a deep, embedded meaning inside these words that allows their meanings to be used somewhat similarly.  Because even though most people used the word `contraseña` for `password`, I also know that `clave` is used sometimes instead.  And in my humble opinion, a password is pretty much the same as a key, well, more like a code, I suppose.

Comment: I'm not sure about _key_ equivalent in Spanish when is used to _music instruments_ (I only know _tecla, cuerda, or the name of the piece in the musical instrument_), but the word _clave_ is the most frequent that I use in the examples that you provided.

Comment: When refering to the symbol in score, the _treble clef_ may be called either _llave de sol_ or _clave de sol_, at least in Chile.

Comment: Be careful with *clave* in the musical sense. I was using phrases like "this guitar is not in the right key" and was told by my band (in Spain) that clave is the wrong word. Clave refers to the clef symbol in written music (partitura.) The correct translation of *"this guitar is out of key"* is *"esta guitarra está fuera de tono."* A better example: *we play this song in the key of C Minor* = *"tocamos esta canción en el tono de Do Menor."*

Comment: D'oh.. Can't believe that I forgot that I have said `destonado` to reference an out of tune guitar before and been understood.

Comment: @dockeryz the most usual expression for a guitar that is out tune would be `desafinada.` `fuera de tono` gives the idea that it is out of key (though possibly in tune with itself.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "llave" in the context of a faucet may also be called "llave de paso" and is the one that lets the pipes feed the faucet or the whole house water stream:

[image: llave de paso]

We also use "llave" for some tools like ["llave inglesa"](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Llave_inglesa) (Monkey wrench) or ["llave allen"](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Llave_Allen). We also use "llave" for "llave de judo", a movement of the martial art discipline in which you immobilize your opponent.

If we check the [etymology of "llave"](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?llave) we learn that this word comes from latin *clavis*, and then the word evolved from "**Cl**avis" to "**ll**ave".

> La palabra latina *clavis* pasó originalmente al castellano con el sentido de “llave”. Siglos después, en el uso culto, la palabra *clavis* se convirtió en “clave”.
>
> Eso explica que en el fondo una clave es una llave: es algo que sirve para abrir algo que está cerrado, ya sea una cerradura o un misterio oculto.

(quoted from [this reference](http://wordpress.danieltubau.com/la-doble-etimologia-de-fritz-mauthner/))

I don't think that these words are interchangeable. I would favor "contraseña" over "clave" ("clave" has a broader and more abstract meaning to me that a "contraseña") but I would never use "llave" in this context, unless I want to make an analogy like "they open a door to knowledge or to mysteries". I use "llave" for physical things and "clave" for abstract ones.

Comment: `para abrir algo que está cerrado` although very common sense sounding seems to be a good link between the different uses of llave.  Since the water flows when you pull the lever on your sink, you are indeed opening something, the valve as you said.

Comment: Since you also mentioned that wrenches are called llaves as well, it makes me wonder why a screwdriver is called a destornillador.

Comment: We indeed say "**abre** el grifo", for example. A "llave" can do more than open. It could _start_ an engine (llaves del coche). And I forgot to mention another acception of the word "llave": una _llave_ de judo. I don't know how much this has to do with the other ones...

Comment: @Diego Car keys "close" an [electronic circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_network) (a network consisting of a closed loop, giving a return path for the current). _Una llave de judo_ is used to "b/lock" an oponent movement; see [grappling hold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grappling_hold).

Comment: @quantme, Bien visto!

Comment: Also, you may use "llave" for an abstract element, but it becomes a metaphor of "clave", so don't get confused if you find this somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

As Diego said, they both originate from the same latin word, so the meaning is naturally very close.

In general lines, you will talk about a "llave" when it is a **physical** object (house key, water valve). I have heard some (old) Spanish people (my great-granma) even talking about "llaves de luz" (electric switch).

If it is instead an **abstract** concept, you will use "clave" (music key, clue, password, database key...). From the top of my head I cannot recall any usage of "clave" for a physical object.

Comment: There are. The highest brick in an arch is called "clave" in architecture. Two musical instruments are called "clave": a baroque keyboard (also called "clavicordio") and a pair of wooden sticks that are hit. The three words are part of the same family of "clavis" derived words.

Answer (score 4):

There are several pairs of words derived from classical languages that coexist and have similar meanings, but differ in that one remains attached to the root form, and the other evolves according to the Spanish phonological preferences.The name in linguistics for this phenomenon is **doblete** (in Spanish).

I do not know if it's a rule, but I think that the evolved form is closer to the everyday meaning (eg, familiar objects, like "las llaves del auto"), whereas the classic form is used in preference to refer to objects of disciplines or technologies, more abstract concepts (like "ideas clave") and formal style.

Examples besides clave / llave:

> flama / llama
>
> rótula / rodilla
>
> sigilo / sello
>
> macula / mancha
>
> forma / horma
>
> clamar / llamar
>
> foco / fuego
>
> causa / cosa
>
> atónito / tonto
>
> frígido / frío
>
> directo / derecho
>
> cómputo / cuenta
>
> aurícula / oreja
>
> folio / hoja
>
> íntegro / entero

You can find many other examples. The first word of the pair is closer to Latin.

Answer (score 2):

`Llave` generally is the real object to open doors, etc. Except in some situations like others mentioned before: llave de judo, etc.

`Clave` is like a password. It is not tangible.

Comment: _Llave de judo_ is not an exception. It's a metaphor that refers to the objects key and lock.

Comment: It is an exception in my answer. It is not tangible :P

Answer (score 0):

La **llave** sirve para abrir y cerrar, puede ser para una puerta, el paso de un líquido (un grifo), o en sentido figurado el corazón u otras cosas.

**Clave** no tiene nada que ver, aunque en inglés se use la misma palabra.

Clave puede ser el conjunto de reglas y correspondencias que explican un código. Entiendo que en inglés pueden usar la misma palabra porque lo interpretan como "abre un mensaje o canal de comunicación".

Clave también es 
"algo importante", 
"un instrumento musical", 
"Con el carácter o el tono de", 
o 
"Signo que se pone al principio del pentagrama para determinar el nombre de las notas"

Comment: "Clave no tiene nada que ver" Incorrecto, tiene mucho que ver, etimológicamente y semánticamente.

Comment: No tiene nada que ver con la primera frase, con mi explicación, con algo que sirve para abrir y cerrar físicamente algo, aunque como ya puse sí que se puede interpretar como que abre un mensaje o canal de comunicación.