# "Dicho" vs "maldito" y "bendito"

Tags: etimología, verbos, historia, participio

Ayer empecé a ver *[Kubo y las dos cuerdas mágicas](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4302938/?ref_=nv_sr_1)*, y hay un momento que me resultó bastante divertido, cuando un personaje dice repetidamente que está maldito, y de repente se queda pensando y dice "¿maldito o maldecido?".

A partir de ahí ya el que se quedó pensando fui yo. Si verbos como *[maldecir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=O0XKKDz)* o *[bendecir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5LQ5waj)* son compuestos del verbo *decir*, y el participio de este es *dicho*, ¿por qué los participios irregulares son *maldito* y *bendito*, y no *maldicho* y *bendicho*? ¿O por qué no es *dito* el participio de *decir*, manteniendo la *t* como en italiano? ¿De dónde viene ese cambio de *t* por *ch*?

Comment: El cambio sería más bien de -ct- a -ch-, un proceso de hecho bastante común (octo > ocho, lactem > leche). Es decir, del latín *dictus* obtenemos *dicho* (ver *dictar, dictamen*). De hecho, las formas *maldicto*, *maledicto*, *bendicto* y *benedicto*  se encuentran en el CORDE hasta aproximadamente el siglo XVI. Es relativamente común encontrar un participio irregular adaptado a la fonología o morfología actuales en algunos verbos pero con la forma más similar al latín en compuestos del mismo verbo (decimos *roto* pero *corrupto*, *nacido* pero *innato*). Por qué, no sabría decir.

Comment: @Yay a mí me vale como posible respuesta. :-)

Comment: Sospecho que maldito y bendito llegaron al castellano más tarde, entonces se saltearon la transformación ct --> ch que menciona Yay, algo así como lo que pasó con *hueso* (más antigua) y *oseo* (más nueva). Pero sólo estoy conjeturando.

Comment: @Wences: Según Corominas, "decir" aparece a mediados del siglo X, "bendecir" hacia 1140 y "maldecir" hacia 1200. No aporta las fechas de "maldito" y "bendito", pero sí dice que bendecir deriva directo del latín _benedicere_ y maldecir de _maledicere_. Es decir, no fueron compuestas en español, sino que nos llegaron compuestas desde el latín.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @Yay Es algo común que en algunos grupos de palabras con la misma raíz tengan una pronunciación diferente, debido a que algunas palabras de ese grupo se quedaron atrás en el tiempo. Un ejemplo especifico en México por ejemplo es Hierro y Fierro, ambas palabras existen y son usadas con frecuencia (sin importar nivel socio-económico). Sin embargo son usadas en diferentes contextos. "La estructura del edificio es de hierro sólido" y "Lo golpeó con un fierro". En fin es muy buena pregunta..... por cierto cuando yo cocino usualmente salteo los vegetales.

Comment: @Maurocrispin: el concepto se llama "doblete". [Aquí](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/12293/6915) hay más ejemplos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El cambio fonético en cuestión tuvo en realidad dos partes: primero fue un paso de *-ct-* a *-it-* (quizá vía algún otro paso intermedio) y luego de *-it-* a *-ch-* por palatalización de la *t* (y con cambio de *a* precedente por *e*). Se puede observar cómo en el portugués este mismo cambio se quedó a medio camino (*noite* "noche", *leite* "leche", *oito* "ocho", *peito* "pecho", etc.).

Este cambio fonético no afectó a todas las palabras por igual sino que, como ocurre habitualmente, las que eran más formales o específicas a algún registro fueron pasadas por alto. Además hubo palabras que fueron adoptadas del latín después de haberse producido el cambio.

El verbo "decir" es sumamente común, pero "bendecir" ya no lo es tanto y su participio menos todavía. Si la palabra *bendecir* hubiese sido acuñada a partir de *decir* en su forma moderna, seguramente diríamos *bendicho* (o *biendicho*), pero dado que ya existía en latín, imagino que simplemente persistió con cambios menores. La simplificación de *-ct-* en *-t-* no es un cambio regular pero está en la misma línea que la de otros grupos consonánticos.

Sería interesante saber cómo la gente pronunciaba realmente *maldicto* y *bendicto*, según aparecen en escritos españoles antiguos, ya que la ortografía es siempre más conservadora que la lengua hablada.